# Why do I get this "Invalid prop: expected Array, got String" error?

Tags: vue.js

In my child component I expect an array prop:

```
export default {
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```

In my parent component I define an array of objects:

```
data () {
  return {
    listItems: [
      {
        text: 'blabla'
      },
      {
        text: 'blibli'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

..and call the child component this way:

```
<custom-list items="listItems" />
```

Yet Vue complains that listItems is a string. How can it be a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `<custom-list items="listItems" />` you are just passing a static string.
You have to change it to `v-bind:items` or in short form `:items` to pass the array to your component. The `v-bind` colon in front is used to tell vue that the value being passed is a javascript expression or a data type other than a string.

For example: 
`<custom-list :items="listItems" />` or `<custom-list v-bind:items="listItems" />`

Comment: Wow that's embarrassing. Thanks :)